# Correct Syntax for write function

Tags: python, excel, pandas, syntax, xlrd

I would like to use the size of the lists that I created (col_test) for indexing the write function but I do not know how to do this, and for that matter I don't know the syntax for the write function well at all. I want to populate the columns in the new sheet with the lists I created starting in row 6 of column 1.

```
import os
import glob
import pandas as pd

for csvfile in glob.glob(os.path.join('.', '*.csv')):
    df = pd.read_csv(csvfile)

col_test = df['Test #'].tolist()
col_retest = df['Retest #'].tolist()

from xlrd import open_workbook
from xlutils.copy import copy

rb = open_workbook("Excel FDT Master_01_update.xlsx")
wb = copy(rb)

s = wb.get_sheet(3)
s.write(6,0:17,0, col_test)
wb.save('didthiswork.xls')
```

Comment: Are you coming from R? This would be easier done with `list(range(0, 17))` assuming the second parameter accepts a list.

Comment: Coming from Matlab